# Hosting Angular SPA on AWS S3 with Authentication Redirects

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, angular2-routing

Our SPA is written in Angular (ie Angular2, Angular4. Not AngularJS) and authenticates using OAuth2 against Azure AD.  We are using an [OIDC library](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc) to handle the authentication.

The application is hosted in an AWS S3 bucket configured to serve a static website.  For argument's sake, let's pretend the URL is `myapp.example.com`.

When the user clicks the login button, they are redirected to a microsoft page to handle the authentication. So far, so good.  Once they have authenticated, they are redirected back to `myapp.example.com/login`.

However there is no artifact in my S3 bucket named `login`.  The `login` route is handled by the Angular router, and calls a component within my app.  This all works fine in development when I'm running on my local machine.  But when I run the version hosted in S3, redirection back to `myapp.example.com/login` fails with a 404 error.

I understand the reason for the error - there isn't an artifact named `login` in my S3 bucket.  But I imagine this would be a problem for just about any link in my app.  For example, if I shared a link to `myapp.example.com/objects/1234` with another user, I imagine that would 404 for them, too.

So the question is, what do I need to do to properly host this SPA in AWS so that redirection and other links work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old topic, but I found this while working on a similar project. Using Lambda is not ideal or necessary so I am including this as an updated answer to help other people searching for this issue.

This issue is actually in the [Knowledge Center](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/404-error-nosuchkey-s3/).

> Note: If a requested object doesn’t exist in the bucket and the
>   requester doesn’t have s3:ListBucket access, then the requester
>   receives an HTTP 403 Access Denied error rather than an HTTP 404
>   error. If this is the case, you must resolve the issue related to the
>   missing object to address the HTTP 403 error.

You just need to do 2 things.

1. Add a [custom error page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/custom-error-pages.html) to CloudFront
2. Update your bucket policy

**1)** With the distribution created, click on the ID of the distribution to get back into the settings. You should see multiple tabs and one of them being *Error Pages*. Click on *Error Pages* and then click on *Create Custom Error Response*. From here, you need to setup a redirect for 404 handling to ensure your SPA works properly

Set:

- *HTTP Error Code* to **404: Not Found**
- *Error Caching Minimum TTL (seconds)* to whatever value you want, default work. This is your caching.
- *Custom Error Response* to **Yes**
- *Response Page Path* to **/index.html**
- *HTTP Response Code* to **200: OK**

**2)** We learned from the Knowledge Center that if the object doesn't exist, and you do not have `s3:ListBucket` you get a 403 instead of a 404. When testing we notice that you actually get `NoSuchKey`. Ok, the Knowledge Center gave us the solution so we just need to update the bucket policy.

If you setup this properly, CloudFront Origin Access Identity should already be set to the bucket policy. It will look something like:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity ORIGIN_ACCESS_ID"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now you just need to add the new parameter. It's also important to note that this new parameter uses a different resource. So the new policy should now look similar to:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontOriginAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity ORIGIN_ACCESS_ID"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Your SPA should now work as expected without any Lambda hacks.

Reference: [Guide I wrote while working on a similar project](https://www.jeremysimkins.com/thoughts/aws/how-to-host-spa-on-aws-with-s3-and-cloudfront/)

Comment: This answer and the linked blog post we're super helpful. Wish I had them when I was dealing with this!

Answer (score 1):

Configure AWS CloudFront in front of S3 and do the domain mapping for CloudFront(With CNAME). Then using [AWS Edge Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html), you can rewrite the URL for /login to direct to the index.html.

This will load the index.html also for the /login path and trigger the route in Angular from client side, after redirection happens.

Comment: No need for Lambda, CloudFront can do this behaivor simply by adding error page policy.